# Oauth verification error

Tags: android, oauth, verification

I am trying to use Oauth for verification. My example code is:

```
ArrayList <NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
  boolean flag=false;
  URL url;

  String oauth_nonce="q14F5ApN4Ka5RJGbYgabXwMSZ4BxVrlNGedN9zoFAoi3rc7dpLjIgri1erAAriPu";
  String oauth_timestamp="1336069726";
  String signatureString =
    URLEncoder.encode("device_id=id_here")
    +URLEncoder.encode("&device_type=psw_here")
    +URLEncoder.encode("&oauth_consumer_key=consumer_key_here...&oauth_nonce=" +
      oauth_nonce+
      "&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1336069726&oauth_version=1.0");

  String percent_encoded_url = URLEncoder.encode("http://www.example.com");
  String signatureBaseString = "POST"+
    "&"+percent_encoded_url+
    "&"+signatureString;

  String oauth_signature=URLEncoder.encode(computeHmac(signatureBaseString, "aWAQTWR7VvHapaNhWBCL0VaUdGN2xzN4&"));

  String headerValue ="OAuth "+
    "oauth_consumer_key=\""+"consumer_key_here..."+"\","+
    "oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1"+"\","+
    "oauth_signature=\""+oauth_signature+"\","+
    "oauth_timestamp=\"1336069726"+"\","+
    "oauth_nonce=\""+oauth_nonce+"\"," +        
    "oauth_version=\"1.0"+"\"";


  HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.example.com/");

  httppost.setHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  httppost.setHeader("Authorization",headerValue);
  HttpEntity httpentity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params);

  HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(clientConnectionManager, httpparams);

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  try {

   HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

When I send request, it always says 'Bad Signature Match'. I have no knowledge of Oauth. I have no idea where I am wrong. Can someone guide me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are generating the signature in the correct way, but that the server responds with a generic `signature mismatch` message because:

**First**, you cannot use the same nonce for every request. You need to generate a new nonce, randomly for every request.

**Second**, the timestamp needs to be current time in UTC, for every request. If the OAuth provider is correctly implemented, it will allow for timestamps that are in the very near future or past. So make sure your clock is correct.

From what I can tell your signature generation looks ok, at least if you are attempting to get a request token. Try with the two points above and let me know how it goes :)